# How do you perform a SUM query through visual basic?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

**I am trying to to add up the points a certain user has earned from a mysql database table**

My code returns an error saying the syntax is incorrect, I can't figure out how to make it work>

Here is my code:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Leaderboard
Dim MysqlConn As MySqlConnection
Dim COMMAND As MySqlCommand
Private Sub submitBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles submitBtn.Click
    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString =
    "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root99;database=database"
    Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
 Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select SUM(Points) * from database.progress where candidate_number_fk = '" & textbox_can.Text & "'"
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
        READER = Command.ExecuteReader
        MessageBox.Show("You have successfully submitted your score")
        MysqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
    My.Forms.Menu1.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is incorrect SQL syntax:

```
select SUM(Points) *
from database.progress
where . . .
```

Presumably, you intend:

```
select SUM(Points) as sumpoints
from database.progress
where . . .
```

You can then pull the field from the result set by name.

Note:  There may be other problems with your code.  This only addresses the SQL query.

Comment: I changed it to: select SUM(Points) as sumpoints from database.progress where candidate_number_fk = '" & textbox_can.Text & "'"  then return the value using messagebox.show(sumpoints), this just returns 0 whn it should return 10, i'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: @Niam . . . It will return 0 when the sum is zero.  You need to check and double check the `FROM` clause.